# How long was the trip from Earth to Mars for Insight?

Tags: mars, earth, insight

How long was the trip from Earth to Mars for Insight from blastoff to landing?

Comment: I thoroughly searched using the Space Exploration Search page referenced in that section, this question had not been asked yet and so no results came back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to NASA's [launch timeline](https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/timeline/launch/), InSight launched at 5 May 2018, 12:05 PM UTC.

According to the [up-to-date InSight Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InSight), InSight landed at 26 November 2018, 19:54 UTC.

This means that the entire trip took [205 days, 7 hours, and 49 minutes](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=05&d1=05&y1=2018&m2=11&d2=26&y2=2018&h1=12&i1=05&s1=00&h2=19&i2=54&s2=00).

Comment: Welcome to Space Exploration! As neither of the cited times included a seconds figure, I'm going to edit out the seconds from your otherwise devastatingly precise answer.